# BottomNavigationView Does not work

Tags: java, android

I am working with BottomNavigationView, but the application does directly stopped and give me an error at line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

this is my code ( I did not do anything yet )

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

xml file :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:Design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.ahmad.testbottomnavigationbar.MainActivity"
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
   />
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/NavBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    Design:menu="@menu/menu_nav">
```

And Menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/news"
    android:title="news" />
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/sug"
    android:title="sugg" />
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/fav"
    android:title="fav" />
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/myhome"
    android:title="home" />

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/comp"
    android:title="complain" />

<item

    android:icon="@drawable/myaccount"
    android:title="account" />
```

and finally dependacies :

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

and the application stopped after running , 
this is the exception :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.ahmad.testbottomnavigationbar/com.example.ahmad.testbottomnavigationbar.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: is <sandroid.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView or  <android.support... ?

Comment: xml not find class `<sandroid.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`, use proper class path.

Comment: `sandroid.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` typo. It should be `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`

Comment: the problem not with sandroid

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/NavBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
Design:menu="@menu/menu_nav">
```

**Replace**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     android:id="@+id/NavBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"/>
```

Comment: you are close your menu "</menu>" in menu.xml

Answer (score 1):

There is Typing mistake channge `<sandroid` to `<android`

**Use this**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/NavBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    Design:menu="@menu/menu_nav">
```

**Instead of**

```
<sandroid.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/NavBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    Design:menu="@menu/menu_nav">
```

**EDIT**

use this

```
app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
```

**instead of this**

```
Design:menu="@menu/menu_nav">
```

Comment: thank but the mistake just here , in my code it like this
<sandroid.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: thank but the mistake just here , in my code it like this
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: the problem is not with sandroid ,

Comment: @wadi3a1golden also with this **`<sandroid`**

Comment: i remove it but still have same exception , i read about it , 
some one talked about style and should edit it but i can not under stand

Comment: sorry ? i do not think i understand you , 
error not solved

Comment: No , Not Solved

Comment: unfortunately not solved be replace design by app , 
does the android studio version related to this problem ?
i am with 3.0 beta 2

Comment: i added 6 items , so i think there is wrong with that , when i deleted one of them it works fine , i can not under stand why , but it solved ,

Comment: UPDATE

As per different stackoverflow question, you also need to update proguard configuration file (e.g. proguard-rules.pro), code above uses reflection and won't work if proguard obfuscate the mShiftingMode field.

-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { 
    boolean mShiftingMode; 
} 
do you know how to do this ?

Comment: this is wrong answer but right answer  is @wadi3a1 comment, remove one item in menu.

Answer (score 1):

Add **compile 'com.android.support:transition:26.1.0'** to your app build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

make new layout .....(yourBottomNavLayoutName)
{sandroid.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView} sandroid is invalid because of misspell use android.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dem60"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/appblue"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colortextlightblue"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        android:elevation="@dimen/dem10"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnavitems"/>
```

and include this layout in your main activity like this

```
<include
            layout="@layout/yourBottomNavLayoutName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: i have just one activity , and should not include main activity here

Answer (score 0):

You need to just modify and remove "s" from begining of below code

```
 <sandroid.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

to

  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

**AND**

check [Link](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android)

Hope it's helps you.

Comment: thank but the mistake just here , in my code it like this
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: you get me wrong , the problem is still exist not solved

Comment: i deleted " s" but still exsist

Comment: ok @wadi3a1golden please check this hope it's helps you :-https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android

Comment: UPDATE

As per different stackoverflow question, you also need to update proguard configuration file (e.g. proguard-rules.pro), code above uses reflection and won't work if proguard obfuscate the mShiftingMode field.

-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { 
    boolean mShiftingMode; 
}
do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a navigation file (found in res/navigation) and your ids need to match between the two.  Example:

```
<!-- found in res/menu/menu_nav -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_news"
    android:icon="@drawable/news"
    android:title="news" />

<!-- found in res/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_news"
    android:name="com.whatever.NewsFragment"
    android:label="News"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news" />
```